# Using for loop incorrectly

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

In the following code the for loop is never executed. I have attempted to fix the problem with breakpoints and watches. The correct length for the cipher text is returned, however the for loop does not increment until `int i >= ciphertext.length()`. In fact, nothing seems to execute past the 'Debug' message.

```
private void decrypt_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


    String alphabet= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    String ciphertext="fRcXFBxXTRJ";


    status_label.setText( "Decryption has begun" );

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ciphertext-length: " + ciphertext.length() + "\n" + ciphertext,"Debug", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    for (int i = 0; i>=ciphertext.length(); i--){

        System.out.println("inc:" + i);

        String cipher_current_char = getLetterAtIndex(ciphertext, i);
        int pos_char_in_alphabet = getIndexAtLetter(alphabet, cipher_current_char);


        if(pos_char_in_alphabet-2<0){

            plain_ta.setText(getLetterAtIndex(alphabet, (alphabet.length()+(pos_char_in_alphabet -2)+1 ) ));

            status_label.setText( 100/i + "%");



        }else{

            cipher_current_char = getLetterAtIndex(ciphertext, i);

            pos_char_in_alphabet = getIndexAtLetter(alphabet, cipher_current_char);

            plain_ta.setText(getLetterAtIndex(alphabet, (pos_char_in_alphabet-2)));

            status_label.setText( 100/i + "%");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. :-) One time of setting a breakpoint on the `if` statement and examining the values when it was hit would have explained the problem you're having.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (int i = ciphertext.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
```

You need to work backwards. Also note the `-1`, you need it to avoid out of bounds exceptions (indexes start at `0` and go to `length -1` ).

Always trace your loop out loud with paper and pencil when you're stuck, it always helps.

Comment: Shouldn't, the check happens before actually executing the rest of the loop and decrementing. As in: *is i>= 0? Yes, execute loop body, decrement i, check again, etc*

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about that.. kwl

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = ciphertext.length()-1; i > 0; i--){
```

You need to reverse the condition, otherwise logic is wrong..

Comment: You're off-by-one; the `length()` is one past the end.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I strongly suggest that you learn how to use your IDE's debugger. You should also learn how to add `System.out.println()` calls to your code for debugging purposes.

With that said, let's look at the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i>=ciphertext.length(); i--)
```

Let's say you have reached the for loop and `ciphertext` has a length of 10. `i` is initialized to zero. Then the condition check if it is *greater than* or equal to 10. Nope it isn't, so the whole for loop is skipped.

Note that the condition of a for loop must be true for the loop to continue. It is *not* used to tell the for loop when to stop.

So we can fix this problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i<=ciphertext.length(); i--)
```

Now the for loop starts with `i` at 0. This is less than or equal to 10, so the loop executes. `i` is decremented to -1, which again is less than or equal to 10. The loop is executed and `i` is decremented to -2...

I see a pattern here. The loop won't stop. We need to make another change:

```
for (int i = 0; i<=ciphertext.length(); i++)
```

Now `i` increases from 0 to 10. However, when `i` is 10, you will get an exception. This is because the only valid indices are from 0 to **9**. One last fix will change the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i<ciphertext.length(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i>=ciphertext.length()
```

should be

```
i < ciphertext.length()
```